# FileUpload in C# with PHP Server

Tags: c#, php

I am currently working on a fileUploader in the C# language for a image hosting site I develop for, I am currently wondering what the best approach is to uploading files to the server(all php/sql) with the client software being C#.

Also, how would I process these uploads in a PHP script, would you say something along the lines of:

```
upload.php?appfile=filepath?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and its [UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx):

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UploadFile("http://www.example.com/upload.php", "somefile.dat");
}
```

The [UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) uses the **POST** method to upload the file to the HTTP resource; you need to set up your PHP script accordingly.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for that! Considering it uses POST, what will it post as? Regards

Comment: The method uploads the files in "multipart/form-data" format. You should be able to access them using [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php); see [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).